# WPF Grid - Drawing Custom Grid Lines

Tags: wpf, xaml

Say I have a very simple WPF grid (6 rows x 6 columns) defined as follows:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I want the following grid lines (one solid line and two dashed lines) drawn as follows (I drew this in Excel so ignore the light Excel grid lines):

[image]

How might I go about doing this in XAML?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can place `Line`s at the tops of the required cells, by setting `VerticalAlignment="Top"`, the appropriate `Grid.ColumnSpan`, and set `StrokeDashArray` to get the dashed line.

Edit: The above was just off the top of my head, and I apparently forgot about a few 'features' of WPF.

Here is the sample I got working. I put it in a Grid with 5 rows and columns, star-sized.

```
<Line Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"
    X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
<Line Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="5,3"
    X2="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Note: If rows will vary in size, that won't work, since it centers the line in the two rows. If they will vary in size, you will need `VerticalAlignment="Top"`, but beware, the top half of the line will be clipped.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested, but for some reason, the line does not display. My XAML is as follows:            <Line Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>

Comment: My bad. I think that's because the Line is weird in that it can stretch without the line actually stretching. I'm looking for a solution.

Comment: @RandyMinder Did you set the `X2` property? It defines the width of the line